# Taco roadmap - Update 11 with Cordova 7 support

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova, taco

Are there any plans by Microsoft to release a Taco Update 11 with native Cordova 7, Node 4.x support?
Is Taco still an active project since the [last update](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release-update-10/) was two years ago?

Comment: How would we know what Microsoft is thinking? Does taco not have their own forum or repository where you could check?

Comment: @Rob No, they do not have any forum for this specific project. Also, I would add that I have more possibilities to reach [somebody of the team](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4612324/subhag-oak) from here.

Comment: He hasn't been here in a year and a half.

Comment: @Rob could be a clue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it is safe to assume Microsoft has abandoned TACO platform, putting their focus in this space to Xamarin.

- As you pointed out, the last update to the tool was 2 years ago, Jan 2016.
- The [last entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/10/20/answers-to-your-top-taco-questions) in The Visual Studio Blog ("The official source of product insight from the Visual Studio Engineering Team") was 15 months ago, Oct 2016.
- According to his [LinkedIn profile, Jordan Matthiesen](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jordanmatthiesen/), who was Program Manager for VS Taco, is now Program Manager for Visual Studio For Mac.

For myself, a Visual Studio user for 27 years, I have switched to using Cordova CLI and Visual Studio Code on Mac.

Comment: Returning from VS2015 to the CLI is not exactly moving forward, now you have to manually install plugins, platforms, compile, deploy, debug... all stuff that VS2015 does automatically with the click of a button.

Comment: @andreszs That is true, from a VS user perspective (as I also am). But it still appears MS VS team has abandoned Cordova development, for the reasons I stated above.

Comment: And just a followup, reinforcing this view.  Microsoft just rehomed their development blogs to new address, new layout.  I was surprised to see a link for Apache Cordova under "popular tags", so I clicked on the link.  Alas, the newest post is 2 1/2 years old (Aug 2016). <sigh>

Answer (score 3):

After a few try i have found a way:

**Follow this steps:**

1. install **nodejs 4.8.7** on your machine
2. in visual studio go under tools>options>"Tools for apache cordova"
       and deflag chekbox "**use a sandboxed version of NodeJS**"
3. Edit **taco.json** file of your project and set **"cordova-cli": "7.1.0"**
4. Open a new console and install cordova on your machine (**npm install
   -g cordova@7.1.0**)

**For android build:**

1. open prompt, digit **android** and press return
2. dovnload **API 26 SDK** from tool
3. download **gradle 2.x** and put bin folder in your system path
4. install **jdk 1.8.x** and set **java_home** system var to it
   reboot

Comment: Thanks this works, but VS2015 persists in using cordova-android 6.3.0, how can we force it to use at least cordova-android 7.0.0?

Comment: Cordova@7.1.0 contains cordova-android@6.3.0, if you want to use more updated version you can use cordova@8.0.0, or you can try to set in your taco.json "cordova-android":"7.0.0" after "cordova-cli" version, if is compatible with CLI 7.1. Version of cordova and subplatform is not the same (es. cordova-ios is 4.3 on cordova@7.1.0, and the edge is cordova-ios 4.5). Hope it helps.

Comment: And keep care about compatibility issues with old plugins and android API version to install for build in major cordova-android versions.

Comment: You are right, Cordova 7.1.0 still uses cordova-android 6.3.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those that still use TACO for visual studio, I found the following instructions to update Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova for VS 2017 to use Cordova @7.1.0 and Cordova-Android @6.3.0

https://github.com/brunolau/vs-taco-update

It tells you how to find the old toolset (6.3.1) and how to replace it with a new version, and also how to update android to API level 26.

It also shows you how to create your own custom toolset, which I haven't tried, but sounds very useful.