# VS2017 Cordova. Can't install Push Plugin because Cordova vrs 7.1 required

Tags: android, push-notification, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to add Push Notifications to a blank VS2017 Cordova app but it appears the Cordova version 6.3.1 may not be sufficient. 
*(Warning: Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 6.3.1, failed version requirement: >=7.1.0)*

Is there anyway to update this in visual studio?
Has the Microsoft team possibly giving up on Cordova? It seems suspect.

```
Installing plugin 'phonegap-plugin-push'
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
No version specified for phonegap-plugin-push, retrieving version from config.xml
No version for phonegap-plugin-push saved in config.xml
Attempting to use npm info for phonegap-plugin-push to choose a compatible release
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat""
Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat"
Warning: Unmet project requirements for latest version of phonegap-plugin-push:
Unmet project requirements for latest version of phonegap-plugin-push:
Warning:     cordova-android (5.2.1 in project, >=7.1.0 required)
    cordova-android (5.2.1 in project, >=7.1.0 required)
Warning:     cordova (6.3.1 in project, >=7.1.0 required)
    cordova (6.3.1 in project, >=7.1.0 required)
Warning: Current project does not satisfy the engine requirements specified by any version of phonegap-plugin-push. Fetching latest version of plugin anyway (may be incompatible)
Current project does not satisfy the engine requirements specified by any version of phonegap-plugin-push. Fetching latest version of plugin anyway (may be incompatible)
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "phonegap-plugin-push"
Fetching plugin "phonegap-plugin-push" via npm
Copying plugin "C:\Users\randall.tomes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\phonegap-plugin-push\2.2.2\package" => "C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-push"
Calling plugman.install on plugin "C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\plugins\phonegap-plugin-push" for platform "android
Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat""
Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat"
Warning: Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 6.3.1, failed version requirement: >=7.1.0
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 6.3.1, failed version requirement: >=7.1.0
Warning: Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for android
Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for android
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Found "merges/android" folder. Copying its contents into the android project.
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms\android\platform_www, merges\android] to platforms\android\assets\www
  copy  platforms\android\platform_www\cordova_plugins.js platforms\android\assets\www\cordova_plugins.js (updated file)
Wrote out android application name "some game" to C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml
android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (1.0.0): 10000
Wrote out Android package name "com.testapp.somegame" to C:\WSP\App\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\src\com\testapp\somegame\MainActivity.java
Updating icons at platforms\android\res
Updating splash screens at platforms\android\res
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_add".
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [Taco roadmap - Update 11 with Cordova 7 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080658/taco-roadmap-update-11-with-cordova-7-support/49357659#49357659)

In my answer i have reported how to upgrade **TACO** to **cordova 7.1.0**:

> **Follow this steps:**
>
> - install nodejs 4.8.7 on your machine
> - in visual studio go under tools>options>"Tools for apache cordova" and
>     deflag chekbox "use a sandboxed version of NodeJS"
> - Edit **taco.json** file of your project and set "cordova-cli": "7.1.0"
> - Open a new console and install cordova on your machine (npm install -g
>     cordova@7.1.0)
>
> **For android build:**
>
> - open prompt, digit android and press return
> - download API 26 SDK from
>     tool
> - download gradle 2.x and put bin folder in your system path
> - install jdk 1.8.x and set java_home system var to it
> - reboot

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of when down the road of my own hybrid apps by using javascript to communicate with a webbrowser view in native. I am a little concerned about going Cordova, or Xamarin for that matter, and not being able to use other features of a phone app (outside of a hello world app) like Admob, Facebook login, notifications and any other third party libraries that have a more solid ecosystem and support for native as apposed to wrapper frameworks. Just seems like anytime you try to do anything outside of a simple hello world app with these frameworks you hit a brick road.